# component not reading hook state properly

Tags: reactjs

I have an button (h1) component that has an onclick handler (handleDateLabelClick) that changes the state to decide whether or not a calendar is visible or not. Working properly, it should change the state to whatever the opposite currently is. Currently, clicking the button correctly causes the calendar to appear, but clicking the same button again does not cause the calendar to disappear. I've added a console log to the handleDateLabelClick function to see what is being read, and each time the calendarOpen state is false. This gets even more interesting when I observe in devtools that the state is operating correctly (true when open, false when closed). Here is my code (BookCard is parent of Calendar):

BookCard

```
const BookCard = ({
   ...props
}) => {
const [calendarOpen, setCalendarOpen] = useState(false)

const handleDateLabelClick = () => {
    setCalendarOpen(!calendarOpen)
}

<DateWrapper>
    <DateHeading onClick={handleDateLabelClick} level={4}>
        {parsedDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', dateFormat)}
    </DateHeading>
    <Calendar
        handleChooseDate={handleChooseDate}
        calendarOpen={calendarOpen}
        setCalendarOpen={setCalendarOpen}
        {...props}
    />
</DateWrapper>
```

Calendar

```
const EnhancedCalendar = ({
  handleChooseDate,
  calendarOpen,
  setCalendarOpen,
  ...props
}) => {

  EnhancedCalendar.handleClickOutside = () => setCalendarOpen(false)

  return (
    <StyledCalendar
      calendarOpen={!!calendarOpen}
      showNeighboringMonth
      minDetail="month"
      onClickDay={handleChooseDate}
      activeStartDate={props.experienceDate}
      tileDisabled={({ activeStartDate, date, view }) => date < new Date()}
      tileDisabled={({ activeStartDate, date, view }) => {
        const availabilitiesForCurrentDate = getTimesForCurrentDate(date, props.detail.availabilities)
        return (
          !availabilitiesForCurrentDate.length
        )
      }}
    />
  )
}

const clickOutsideConfig = {
  handleClickOutside: () => EnhancedCalendar.handleClickOutside
}

export default onClickOutside(EnhancedCalendar, clickOutsideConfig)
```

[image]

Comment: how is the calendar using `setCalendarOpen` ?

Comment: I have a hook in Calendar that detects if there is a click outside of the calendar. it is executed at that point from within Calendar.

Comment: so a click on the title would be a click outside of the calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your comment:

> I have a hook in Calendar that detects if there is a click outside of
>   the calendar. it is executed at that point from within Calendar. And
>   you found the bug spot on!! thank you! The question remains though,
>   how can I keep this functionality without the current bug

I think your Calendar is fighting with your title.

To fix it easily, you could conditionally render your Calendar:

```
<DateWrapper>
    <DateHeading onClick={handleDateLabelClick} level={4}>
        {parsedDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', dateFormat)}
    </DateHeading>
    {calendarOpen ? <Calendar
        handleChooseDate={handleChooseDate}
        calendarOpen={calendarOpen}
        setCalendarOpen={setCalendarOpen}
        {...props}
    /> : null }
</DateWrapper>
```

Comment: I'm attempted to implement your solution, but unfortunately am still having the same issue. Is there something else that I should be modifying also?

I'm curious to know why this solution works. Is it because: when calendarOpen evaluates to false, the component does not exist. Therefore, the HOC that provides the onClickOutside functionality has nothing to wrap ?

Comment: Hmmm... Can you add the relevant code you mentioned from inside the calendar?

Comment: where is `clickOutsideConfig` used?

Comment: its just used to wrap the Calendar. Thought I'd included it. updated